How to query an in-memory "view" of a Neo4j graph?
I want to run Cypher queries on a scoped in-memory graph (akin a "view" in the RDBMS) that would have been extracted from the entire Neo4j graph.
It seems that this apoc is creating the such in-memory graph [1].
CALL apoc.graph.fromCypher(
  'MATCH (p:Person)-[r:DIRECTED]->(m:Movie) RETURN *',
  {},
  'directors',
  {description: "Virtual Graph of all directorships"}
)
YIELD graph AS g
RETURN g;

Questions:

How to run a Cypher query on this directors graph ?
Does the directors graph stay available for various queries during a given user session ?

[1] https://neo4j.com/docs/apoc/current/overview/apoc.graph/apoc.graph.fromCypher/

Virtual nodes/relationships are intended for visualization (e.g., the neo4j Browser can display them), and you cannot use them with most Cypher clauses.
In fact, the doc you mentioned even states:

This procedure returns virtual nodes and relationships that can only
be accessed by other APOC procedures.

Also, virtual nodes/relationships do not persist between queries.

Thanks. But can it be queried with another apoc, sth like:
WITH graph as g CALL apoc.cypher.run('MATCH (n) RETURN n', {graph: g}) YIELD value RETURN value

No, that does not work for 2 reasons. 1. It is using MATCH to access real nodes, not virtual nodes. 2. It actually runs a new query, so any virtual nodes created in your current query would not be available unless you passed them in. But even then you'd still have reason #1.

Sad. Any suggestion on how to sessionize user interactions ? Create views in a middleware (e.g. Python) and run non-Cypher queries on it ? Fall back to SQL ?

You should probably create a new question clearly defining what you mean by "sessionize user interactions", and showing examples of what you have tried. You should also know that stackoverflow is not right forum for DB questions that are too open-ended. You may want to ask at https://dba.stackexchange.com/ instead.

That's why I've asked this in the comment section ;). Thanks.
